Specify "proto_path" globally
Is there any way to specify the proto_path value globally so that an import path could be recognized system wide like import "google/protobuf/Any.proto"? To be particular so that I will not have to place my dependencies manually under the include folder and instead point protoc globally to that path.
Alternatively, if that cannot be done, is there any OS agnostic way to quickly find the absolute path for the Include directory?

Note that this answer may only apply if you are allowed to use buf as your build tool. If it is allowed, then I think it should solve your problem.
However, as google/protobuf packages are supported out of the box, I should instead point you in the direction of some basic dependency management.
Buf has some great tutorials, so check that out also: https://buf.build/docs/bsr/module/dependency-management/
Apart from your basic .proto files, you will need to have a buf.yaml file which includes your project dependencies.
buf.yaml
version: v2
deps:
  - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis  # a random dep
breaking:
  use:
    - FILE
lint:
  use:
    - DEFAULT
    - COMMENTS
  ignore:
    - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis

This way, (IMHO) it is much easier to manage your dependencies, and (hopefully) you will have no more need to download them manually.
You will also need your buf.gen file.
buf.gen.yaml
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
plugins:
  # generate go structs for protocol buffer definitions for java
  # but you can add and remove any plugins necessary
  # See https://buf.build/plugins for more plugins
  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/java
    out: gen/java  # put proto files here

To generate your proto messages, you first need to update your dependencies
buf dep update

issued where your buf.yaml file lives.
And
buf generate

to generate your messages at specified directory.

I never asked for buf.

And hence my first sentence. A lot of questions on SO about protoc seem to miss the fact that there exists great tools for tackling the problem you had. I wouldn't know if you know about buf or not.

You can't set a global proto_path directly within protoc to recognize imports system-wide, but you have some practical workarounds:
Option 1: Use Enviorment Variables
Define an environment variable (like PROTO_PATH) to hold your include path and pass it to protoc each time you compile. This won't make protoc recognize the path automatically but can simplify command syntax.
export PROTO_PATH=/path/to/your/include
protoc -I$PROTO_PATH --proto_path=$PROTO_PATH your_file.proto

This method can work across different environments by setting the environment variable in each OS's respective way (e.g., .bashrc for Unix-based systems or System Environment Variables in Windows).
Option 2: Use a Wrapper Script
Create a wrapper script that points to your common include directory, making it portable across different systems. For example, in a shell script:
#!/bin/bash
INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/your/include
protoc -I$INCLUDE_PATH --proto_path=$INCLUDE_PATH "$@"

Then, run ./your_script.sh your_file.proto, and it will automatically use the specified INCLUDE_PATH.
Option 3: OS-Agnostic Path Resolution
For a more OS-agnostic solution to find the include directory's absolute path, you can use pwd in Unix-based systems or cd commands with batch scripts in Windows to resolve the path dynamically:
Unix Based Systems
INCLUDE_PATH=$(pwd)/include
protoc -I$INCLUDE_PATH --proto_path=$INCLUDE_PATH your_file.proto

Windows - Create a batch file to find the absolute path
@echo off
set INCLUDE_PATH=%cd%\include
protoc -I%INCLUDE_PATH% --proto_path=%INCLUDE_PATH% your_file.proto


This sounds like a ChatGPT answer. When it cannot answer the question then it provides workarounds. But I don't need a workaround.
